# Delphi: how to free form, through parameters?

Tags: delphi

I have 2 forms, I release the form2 through a function passing the parameter form.
Delphi closes the form, however still continues as assigned.

After destroyed the form, still showing assigned!
see example below:

*** Sorry for my English, I'm using google translator

```
{Procedure to destroy form}
procedure TForm1.Destruir(aForm: TForm);
begin
  FreeAndNil(aForm);
end;


{button create form}
procedure TForm1.btnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2:= TForm2.Create(nil);
  Form2.Show;
end;

{button Destroy Form}
procedure TForm1.btnDestroyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Destruir(Form2);
end;


{button Verify}
procedure TForm1.btnVerifyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if Assigned(Form2) then
    ShowMessage('Assigned')
  else
    ShowMessage('unAssigned');

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need the parameter pass to `Destruir` to be a `var` parameter so that the modification you make to the passed argument to modify the passed variable, rather than a local copy of it.

```
procedure TForm1.Destruir(var aForm: TForm);
begin
  FreeAndNil(aForm);
end;
```

Of course, this function is a little needless since you may as well just call `FreeAndNil` directly instead of calling `Destruir`.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why I consider Delphi's documentation on `Destroy`, `Free` and `FreeAndNil` to be somewhat deficient. It leads to unrealistic expetations as to when references will be assigned or not, and poor understanding of common memory/resource management errors.

---

When you have multiple variables referencing a single object (or form), they are all considered "Assigned" because they have a value; the same value pointing to the shared object.

Any one of these references can be used to "destroy" the object. And any of the 3 mehtods above would suffice. `FreeAndNil` will set the *one* reference passed in to **nil**. But ***all other references will be completely unaware the object has been destroyed*** and will still be considered "Assigned".

In your code, `procedure TForm1.Destruir(aForm: TForm);` takes its parameter *by-value*. This means it makes a copy of the input reference. In other words you have 2 references.

```
[Destruir-aForm]-----\
                      [The actual form instance]
[Form2]--------------/
```

So when you call `FreeAndNil(aForm);`, you only set `Destruir-aForm` to **nil**. And `Form2` is still assigned to an invalid object.

```
[Destruir-aForm]--(nil)
                      [Nothing here, Form was destroyed.]
[Form2]--------------/
```

So what you need to do to resolve your problem is pass the parameter *by-reference* using **var**. (*NOTE: **const** is similar to **var** in that it is also passed by reference, but has the limitation you are not allowed to change it.*)

So if you declare `procedure TForm1.Destruir(var aForm: TForm);` then the memory would look somewhat like the following:

```
                                        [The actual form instance]
[Destruir-aForm]=>[Form2]--------------/
```

Now when `FreeAndNil(aForm);`, sets `aForm` to **nil** it also sets `Form2` to **nil**; because they are both **the same thing**. I.e. `Destruir-aForm` is not just a copy.

---

Please be warned that here you may have unintentionally created a copy of the reference to the Form2 by using the wrong parameter declaration in `Destruir`.

But the principle is the same when you explicitly have multiple shared references to the same object. `FreeAndNil` can only set one of those references to **nil**. You need to write your application in a way that you can be sure you don't try to reuse invalid references.

Comment: The documentation for those functions is fine. The issue here is all about the difference between value params and var params. Why would the docs for the functions you mention discuss var params?